# Postgres conditional ordering returning duplicate values

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, timescaledb

We're working with some financial data and need to select trades in specific order, which also depends on type of trades (BUY or SELL). We are using PostgreSQL 12 with TimescaleDB plugin 1.7.2. Trades are stored in a hypertable.

Initially we though about using `CASE WHEN` in `ORDER BY` but as soon as the query hits the `CASE WHEN` part, all rows returned are duplicated. There are **no duplicates** in our table. Here's an example of our initial query:

```
SELECT ticker_id, timestamp, microseconds, price, amount, type FROM tickers
WHERE timestamp >= '2017-08-01T16:00Z' AND timestamp < '2017-08-02T00:00Z' AND fk_exchange = 4 AND fk_trade_pair = 29
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, microseconds DESC, type, CASE WHEN type='BUY' THEN price END DESC, CASE WHEN type='SELL' THEN price END ASC, id DESC;
```

Example of the result, where each row is duplicated:

```
TICKER_ID                               TIMESTAMP               MICROS      PRICE           AMOUNT  TYPE
...
6abdca2a-884e-0f8c-86ee-4afa71435b97    2017-08-01 23:59:00+00  58812000    117.00000000    16910   SELL
6abdca2a-884e-0f8c-86ee-4afa71435b97    2017-08-01 23:59:00+00  58812000    117.00000000    16910   SELL
7f7cfe72-43ca-a153-21a9-e71ddd17ec62    2017-08-01 23:59:00+00  57367000    117.00000000    2085    SELL
7f7cfe72-43ca-a153-21a9-e71ddd17ec62    2017-08-01 23:59:00+00  57367000    117.00000000    2085    SELL
...
```

**EDIT**: And the query plan:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Gather Merge  (cost=5091.03..9691.03 rows=40000 width=115)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|  Workers Planned: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|  ->  Sort  (cost=4091.02..4191.02 rows=40000 width=115)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|        Sort Key: _hyper_14_1591_chunk."timestamp" DESC, _hyper_14_1591_chunk.microseconds DESC, _hyper_14_1591_chunk.type, (CASE WHEN (_hyper_14_1591_chunk.type = 'BUY'::trade_type) THEN _hyper_14_1591_chunk.price ELSE NULL::numeric END) DESC, (CASE WHEN (_hyper_14_1591_chunk.type = 'SELL'::trade_type) THEN _hyper_14_1591_chunk.price ELSE NULL::numeric END), _hyper_14_1591_chunk.id DESC|
|        ->  Result  (cost=6.37..1033.48 rows=40000 width=115)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|              ->  Custom Scan (DecompressChunk) on _hyper_14_1591_chunk  (cost=6.37..433.48 rows=68000 width=51)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|                    Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2020-08-01 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2020-08-02 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on compress_hyper_17_1684_chunk  (cost=45.26..433.48 rows=68 width=252)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|                          Recheck Cond: (fk_trade_pair = 29)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                          Filter: ((_ts_meta_max_1 >= '2020-08-01 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (_ts_meta_min_1 < '2020-08-02 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (fk_exchange = 4))                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on compress_hyper_17_1684_chunk__compressed_hypertable_17_fk_trade  (cost=0.00..45.24 rows=2261 width=0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|                                Index Cond: (fk_trade_pair = 29)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We ended up using the following query but it's more inefficient and feels like a hack-ish way to achieve our desired result:

```
WITH sorted_tickers AS (
    SELECT row_number()
           OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, microseconds DESC, type, CASE WHEN type = 'BUY' THEN price END DESC, CASE WHEN type = 'SELL' THEN price END ASC, id DESC)
               as row_nr,
           timestamp,
           microseconds,
           price,
           amount,
           type
    FROM tickers
    WHERE timestamp >= '2017-08-01T16:00Z'
      AND timestamp < '2017-08-02T00:00Z')
SELECT DISTINCT row_nr, timestamp, microseconds, price, amount, type
FROM sorted_tickers
ORDER BY row_nr ASC;
```

---

If we remove the `CASE WHEN` part from our initial query, we get the expected result without duplicates, although without correct ordering. Are we missing something/using it wrong? Any ideas what would cause the conditional `ORDER BY` to return duplicate rows?

Comment: Can you show EXPLAIN? Have you tested the same query but against normal table (not hypertable)?

Comment: This looks like a timescaledb bug to me.

Comment: Added EXPLAIN of the query. Just tested again with a normal table and it works correctly (no duplicate values). As Bergi pointed out, this indeed looks like a bug with TimescaleDB. I guess I was too fixed on the problem to try the most obvious thing: comparing the result with a normal table. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @matejb Did you report it with timescaledb? Would be nice if you could link the issue. Also I'm curious whether it would triple each row if you added another conditional order.

Comment: @matejb Thank you for the update! I can see from the query plan that the data are compressed. This might be an important detail, so the query might work without compression, but give unexpected result with compression, if you can check this too. I agree that it seems to be a bug and is good to report into [TimescaleDB repo](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues)

Comment: Just submitted the issue in TimescaleDB repo: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/2424. Haven't tried yet without compression though (but plan to try it). @Bergi, tried with three cases and with another conditional statement but wasn't able to triple the rows :)